# I'm having trouble with a regular expression with a lookahead condition

Tags: regex, powershell

This is a regex I will use in a PowerShell script to match if any of the below "Write-*" match unless it is in a comment (comment starts with # and does not need to be at the beginning of a line)
Write-Host
Write-Output
Write-Verbose
Write-Error
Write-Debug
Write-Warning

I suppose I should also take into consideration aliases, but I can cross that bridge once I understand how to properly structure this regex

Regex so far:
`(?i)^(?!.*#).*Write-(Host|Output|Verbose|Error|Debug|Warning).*$`

The below match as expected.

```
Write-Host
Write-Verbose
if ($True){write-Warning}
```

The below does not match as expected.

```
#Write-Host
      # Write-Host
# "command is commented out"    Write-Output
```

I expect the below to match but it does not. What should I change in the regex to make the below match successfully too?

```
Write-output #Comment after command
write-warning  #Write-Warning
```

Comment: I’m sorry this isn’t a helpful comment. I’m just curious as to what you’re trying to accomplish with the regex, what’s your end goal?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a negative lookahead assertion, you can use a character class to exclude `#`s from appearing before `Write-`:

```
(?i)^[^#]*Write-(Host|Output|Verbose|Error|Debug|Warning).*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Ox6xel/1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to handle commands separated by semicolons you'll need a few improvements over @blhsing's answer.

1. Commands can begin at start of line OR after semicolon.  Change first ^ to (?<=^|;)
2. Change the 'not #' string to be non-greedy; `[^#]*` becomes `[^#]*?`.
3. While we cannot exclude the part preceding write-output from the match, we can capture it into group 1 by adding parens and ?: at the right places.
4. There's some nasty context-dependent stuff you need to add to the end because a semicolon without a # starts a new command, while a semicolon after a # is part of a comment.

Doing all this results in,

```
(?im)(?<=^|^[^#]*?;)(?:[^#]*?)(Write-(?:Host|Output|Verbose|Error|Debug|Warning))(?:(?=[^#]*?(;|$))|.*?$)
```

And in Regex101, your examples get captured as
[image]

The green highlight shows what is in capture group 1.

**Edit**
I added a little more to the lookbehind at the beginning to handle the case `# write-Output; write-Output`.  Luckily, .NET has robust lookbehinds allowing variable length lookbehinds; this fix will not work in most other regex implementations.

Comment: This is neat, but with this regex, the below string matches but should not because it is a comment.
'# comment Write-Host;Write-Host'

Comment: I made some fixes in the initial lookbehind that seem to have taken care of that case.  Try it again.